# Unreference reference view

Tags: android, kotlin, view

I'm new at Kotlin and i don't know how to fix this error: Unresolved reference: view. My objective is by pressing button go to the other activity. I copy the code:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        findViewById<Button>(R.id.button).setOnClickListener{
            sendMessage(view)
        }



    }

    val EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.example.monedas.MESSAGE"
    fun sendMessage(it: view) {
        val intent = Intent(this, ListActivity::class.java)
        val editText : TextView = findViewById(R.id.textView4)
        val message = editText.text.toString()
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message)
        startActivity(intent)
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are passing an undefined parameter to the `sendMessage()` function. 
You haven't declared this `view` variable anywhere. 
But it seems that you don't need it, as you don't need the argument `it` of `sendMessage()`. 
So change to:

```
fun sendMessage() {
    val intent = Intent(this, ListActivity::class.java)
    val editText : TextView = findViewById(R.id.textView4)
    val message = editText.text
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message)
    startActivity(intent)
}
```

and call it like this:

```
findViewById<Button>(R.id.button).setOnClickListener{
    sendMessage()
}
```

As a side note:
In Kotlin you don't need to use `findViewById()` if you want  to access the `View`s of the inflated layout in your activity class. 
Just make sure that you have imported:

```
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*
```

and then you can simply do:

```
button.setOnClickListener{ sendMessage() }
```

and in `sendMessage()`:

```
fun sendMessage() {
    val intent = Intent(this, ListActivity::class.java)
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, textView4.text)
    startActivity(intent)
}
```